# Is it possible to dial numbers programatically on the dialer while on an active call..?

Tags: android, phone-call

I have been recently working on an app which requires to respond to an Automatic attendant (virtual  receptionist) which allows callers to be automatically transferred to an extension without the intervention of an operator/receptionist.

My requirement is such that to make a scheduled phone call to a particular number and to respond to the Automatic attendant instructions ("for sales, press 1, for service, press 2," etc)

Is it possible to achieve similar action that i could otherwise achieve by responding to the system manually by pressing an option (say 1 or 2 from above example) programmatically while the call is still active.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this.  There isn't an API, and since the dialer is not part of the OS and can be any app, you can't count on anything working on all devices.

The best chance you have is to assume the dialer will accept USSD input (USSD is an ancient telephony protocol for sending data to phones).  In the USSD language, a comma is a pause.  SO if you want to dial a number, than 1 at the prompt you could ask it to dial "number,,,,1" and hope that the dialer accepts USSD input and that the pause is long enough to dial the 1 at the right time.  But it will work on only a subset of all devices, and be fragile there.

Comment: i got your point. I have already tried that. In that case even though we specify the extension number along with the actual number separated by comma (,) a confirmation popup is displayed to confirm the selection made which requires user input (to confirm the operation). My requirement is to achieve this selection programmatically without the actual interaction of the user. 

Is there any way i could  send DTMF tones on the voice's uplink frequency during an active call..?

Comment: My actual question is ... is there a way to send a DTMF tone while on an active call other than while initiating the call as @gabesechan have mentioned above